# Can't execute shell script in snakemake

Tags: python, shell, snakemake

I recently started using `snakemake` and would like to run a `shell` script in my snakefile. However, I'm having trouble accessing `input`, `output` and `params`. I would appreciate any advice!

Here the relevant code snippets:

1. from my snakefile

```py
rule ..:
    input:
        munged = 'results/munged.sumstats.gz'
    output:
        ldsc = 'results/ldsc.txt'
    params:
        mkdir = 'results/ldsc_results/',
        ldsc_sumstats = '/resources/ldsc_sumstats/',
    shell:
        'scripts/run_gc.sh'
```

2. and the script:

```sh
chmod 770 {input.munged}
mkdir -p {params.mkdir}

ldsc=$(ls {params.ldsc_sumstats})
for i in $ldsc; do
...
```

I get the following error message:

```
...
chmod: cannot access '{input.munged}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{params.ldsc_sumstats}': No such file or directory
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of using `{}` statements applies only to shell scripts defined within `Snakefile`, while in the example you provide, the script is defined externally.

If you want to use the script as an external script you will need to pass the relevant arguments (and parse them inside the shell script). Otherwise, it should be possible to copy-paste the script content inside the `shell` directive and let snakemake substitute the `{}` variables.

Answer (score 1):

From [v7.14.0](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#7140-2022-08-27) Snakemake now supports executing external Bash scripts, with access to snakemake objects inside. See the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#bash) for example usage.